# How to define loss function for an unbalanced dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

I use neural network to do classification. But instead of outputing one label, I want to ouput four independent labels such as [-1,1,1,-1]. Each of them is either 1 or -1, indicating a classification for a specific part of my input(image). However, I have about 3/4 -1s and 1/4 1s in my dataset, so the network tends to predict -1 everywhere, I use a simple mean square error loss now. What can I do to avoid such situation? THX!

Comment: If I am understanding right, your problem is probably something else. I don't think having an unbalanced amount of different target outputs should be an issue. One way you might be able to check is to use mini batches and have it rigged where each batch gets an equal amount of 1s and -1s

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand, you had a 4-part classification problem where each of your outputs was one of the features you were classifying. A common way to get balanced results in classification is by using class weights. At each iteration, the `loss = loss * classweight[c]`, where `classweight` is a dictionary with the inverse of the proportion for each class, in your case `{-1: 4/3, 1: 4}`. Since you need a separate class weight for each output, you could multiply by the vector `[classweight[c] for c in prediction]`, or you could use four separate outputs and multiply each by it's own class weight.